# Ingreso de registro con Ajax a bd

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Hola buen dia a todos espero que me puedan ayudar, la cuestion es que estoy haciendo un panel de control usando ajax, el cliente lo ingreso a 4 tablas diferentes y en las 4 tablas lo ingresa doble el registro. De antemano gracias.

Les dejo el codigo

```js
document.getElementById("btn-agregar-cliente").addEventListener("click",peticion_agregar_cliente)

function peticion_agregar_cliente()
{
 
 var cliente=document.getElementById("cliente-nuevo").value

 if(confirm("¿DESEAS INGRESAR AL CLIENTE: '"+cliente+"' A LA LISTA?"))
 {

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
        
        {
               // codigo para IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
               peticion = new XMLHttpRequest()
               
           } 
           else 
           {
               // codigo para IE6, IE5
               peticion = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
               
           }

          

          var url_agregar="operaciones-bd-panel/agregar-cliente.php?cliente="+cliente

           peticion.onreadystatechange = function() 
           {
               if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
               {
                   document.getElementById("indicador-actualizacion").innerHTML = this.responseText
                   setTimeout(actualizar_lista_clientes,1000)
                   
               }
           };

          peticion.open("GET",url_agregar,true)
          peticion.send()  
 


 }
 
  

    

}
```

```css
/*
Este es el codigo php al momento de invocar ajax

agregar-cliente.php

<?

try 
{ 
 $tablas_actualizar=array("campos_articulos","campos_tiendas","posicion_articulos","posicion_tiendas");

 include("../conexion.php");

 for ($indice=0; $indice <count($tablas_actualizar); $indice++) 
 { 
  $sql="INSERT INTO ".$tablas_actualizar[$indice]." (cliente) VALUES ('".$_GET['cliente']."')";
  $actualizar=$base->query($sql);
  $actualizar->execute();
 }

  echo "CLIENTE ".$_GET['cliente']." AGREGADO";
 

 
} catch (Exception $e)

{
 
  echo "ERROR AL INGRESAR CLIENTE :".$e->getline();
}


?>



*/
```

```html
<html>
<div id="area-agregar-cliente" class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    
    <h4>Agregar cliente</h4>

    <input type="text" id="cliente-nuevo" placeholder="Ingrese cliente">
     
    <input id="btn-agregar-cliente" type="button" value="AGREGAR">

</div>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Dices que se registra dos veces el mismo cliente en las cuatro tablas? En el backend no veo problema. ¿Podrías poner un `console.log` en la función para saber si se está ejecutando dos veces?

Comment: @GustavoGarcía ¿Como obtento el console.log?

Comment: @RICHI150 se refiere a que debugues la función, añade un simple console.log("hola"); en la función Ajax, y mira a ver si se ejecuta una vez o dos, o las que sean.

Comment: @Javi efectivamente si realiza una vez la funcion

Comment: @RICHI150 pues entonces el fallo estará muy probablemente en tu código PHP, intenta investigar un poco más.

Comment: @Javi gracias pues a ver si encuentro ese bug ;)

Comment: @RICHI150 tranquilo lo conseguirás arreglar!!

Comment: cuantas veces ves esto: echo "CLIENTE ".$_GET['cliente']." AGREGADO"; por cada ejecucion?

Comment: @gbianchi solo una vez cada que agrego un cliente nuevo, pero encontre algo raro cuando imprimo $indice me arroja un valor de 4, ¿No de deberia ser un valor de 3?

Comment: no se donde estas mirando eso.. pero para salir del bloque tiene que haber llegado a 4

Comment: @gbianchi si gracias tienes razon

Comment: Listo chavos ya tengo donde esta el error,el error estaba en esta linea $actualizar=$base->query($sql), si la cambio a $actualizar=$base->prepare($sql) ya no me da registros duplicados, ahora la pregunta es: ¿Por que con query ingresa dos registros y con prepare solo uno?